# Javascript remove everything after colon except some words

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have address like this

"8 51209 Rge Rd 950 Road: Rural Parkland County House for sale : MLS®# E4125520"

What i want is I want to remove everything after : but keep Rural Parkland Country. so address becomes this

"8 51209 Rge Rd 950 Road Rural Parkland County"

Just to mention the address is dynamic and not static. i have e.g 10 posts having similar address.

Here is what i have

```
var splittitle = $(".listing-item-entry-title", this).html();
if (splittitle != null){
splittitle = splittitle.replace(/ *\:[^)]*\: */g, ": ");
$(".listing-item-entry-title", this).html(splittitle);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: We can help you on what you've tried yourself.

Comment: you're probably going to want to use regx, but you're going to have to try a few things before we can help you figure out the answer.

Comment: up till now i have this regex.   var splittitle = $(".listing-item-entry-title", this).html();
               
               if (splittitle != null){
               splittitle = splittitle.replace(/ *\:[^)]*\: */g, ": ");
                $(".listing-item-entry-title", this).html(splittitle);
               }

Comment: @SteveBohmbach Sorry i have already tried regex but didn't mentioned in my question

Comment: @Rahul please see what i have done. i updated my question

Comment: @SteveBohmbach anything ?

Comment: I would use @Elisha answer below. Split the string into an array by 
":" and then concat the fist 2 elements of it where ever you need. Im not great with regx so i cant be any help with that. It was just my initial thought of a good way forward before i saw the answer below.

Comment: Is the `for sale` part removed in the return string? If so, do you always have those two words: `for sale` as an indicator that you want to remove everything from there until the end of the string?

Also, for the record, you're not removing from the end of the colon. You're removing some words before it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split the string with the `split(separator, limit)` function and use the first part. Do something like this:

```
var address = "8 51209 Rge Rd 950 Road: Rural Parkland County House for sale : MLS®# E4125520";
var short_addresses = address.split(":", 2);
var short_address2 = short_addresses[1].split(" ", 4).join(' ');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = short_address2;
```

Comment: After colon i want to keep "Rural Parkland County"

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you mark it as the right answer.

Comment: btw this is just giving me "Rural Parkland County" the previous address is also removed by this  ?

Comment: Change the second parameter in short_addresses[1].split(" ", 4).join(' ') to any number of your choice, maybe 5 or 6.